# Daterangepicker is not keyboard accessible

Tags: datepicker, accessibility, daterangepicker

I am using a daterangepicker in my project. It's developed with help of third party library [daterangepicker.js](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) But, it's not supporting keyboard accessibility. Author of this library is not ready to add the feature as it's 11 years old library.

Can someone help me to add the keyboard accessibility for this date picker in my application. I appreciate the suggestions and ideas on this.

More details on exact issue:
We attached the date picker to a input field. And opening the datepicker as soon as input field gets the focus. But, not able to navigate the datepicker using keyboard(arrow, tab etc..)

I am expecting to make date range picker keyboard accessible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking someone to do something on an external site, rather than a self-contained answer which can be given here

Comment: @RobinZigmond Sorry for the confusion. I've to implement this feature on my website not asking to update the 3rd party library. Someone must have faced this issue. I appreciate the suggestions and Ideas.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, but the question is still too broad for SO. You're basically asking for someone to do some work for you - whether to fork the library and add the missing functionality, or to make their own from scratch. Not things you can get from an answer here on SO. You'd do better to find another library - there are hundreds of datepicker libraries out there, I'm sure some are properly keyboard accessible. (And before you ask - no I don't know one to recommend, and in any case asking for library recommendations is also off topic!)

Comment: Before using a library, you should first consider using simple and standard `<input type="date"/>`. They work quite well and are quite accessible on a majority of browsers/OS/devices nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'll explore the other options available instead of making things complex.